# HexaGolf: Wordagons

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, hexagonal-grid

***See also: [Rotatagons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92431/hexagolf-rotatagons)***

### Challenge

Given a string as input, output its wordagon.

### Wordagons

A wordagon is a way of representing a string in a hexagon. Now, let's create a wordagon from the string `hexa`:

Firstly, you start with the first character in the string a place it in the centre:

```
h
```

Then, you take the next character in the string and add a hexagonal layer:

```
 e e
e h e
 e e
```

Then, add the next layer:

```
  x x x
 x e e x
x e h e x
 x e e x
  x x x
```

Finally, add the last layer:

```
   a a a a
  a x x x a
 a x e e x a
a x e h e x a
 a x e e x a
  a x x x a
   a a a a
```

And you now have the wordagon for the string `hexa`.

### Examples

Here's some I prepared earlier:

**`hello`**

```
    o o o o o
   o l l l l o
  o l l l l l o
 o l l e e l l o
o l l e h e l l o
 o l l e e l l o
  o l l l l l o
   o l l l l o
    o o o o o
```

**`PPcg`**

```
   g g g g
  g c c c g
 g c P P c g
g c P P P c g
 g c P P c g
  g c c c g
   g g g g
```

**`o *`**

```
  * * *
 *     *
*   o   *
 *     *
  * * *
```

**`(T_T)`**

```
    ) ) ) ) )
   ) T T T T )
  ) T _ _ _ T )
 ) T _ T T _ T )
) T _ T ( T _ T )
 ) T _ T T _ T )
  ) T _ _ _ T )
   ) T T T T )
    ) ) ) ) )
```

Note that trailing and/or leading newlines are allowed.

### Winning

The shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Bonus points if someone does this in Hexagony? ;)

Comment: Can the input string contain linefeeds? I don't think it would pose any implementation problem, just produce invalid wordagons

Comment: @Aaron No, the input string will never include newlines

Comment: is it ok if the output is a string with newlines returned from a function?

Comment: @Dopapp Yes, that's fine

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You could always start a bounty ;)

Comment: Aww. I'm disappointed because I read the title as "word-dragons"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth - 29 bytes

```
j+_K.e+*kdjdjF+*bhk*L2>zhkztK
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%2B_K.e%2B%2akdjdjF%2B%2abhk%2aL2%3EzhkztK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=hello%0APPcg%0Ao+%2a%0A%28T_T%29%0AWordagon&debug=0).

Answer (score 19):

## Python 2, 83 bytes

```python
s=input()
l=len(s)
while 1:l-=1;y=abs(l);print' '*y+' '.join(s[:y:-1]+s[y]*y+s[y:])
```

Prints the wordagon and then crashes (which only prints to STDERR).

Example:

```
% python2.7 wordagon.py <<<'"abcde"' 2&>/dev/null
    e e e e e
   e d d d d e
  e d c c c d e
 e d c b b c d e
e d c b a b c d e
 e d c b b c d e
  e d c c c d e
   e d d d d e
    e e e e e
```

xnor saved 5 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: You can loop through the `y`'s by doing `n=len(s)\nwhile 1:n-=1;y=abs(n);...` and terminating with error.

Answer (score 10):

## Vim, 92 bytes

```
:se ri|s/./ &/g
ⓋCⓇ"Ⓓ␛$vpmlmrqqYpi ␛`ljxxhmlylv`rjlmr:s/\%V\(.\)./Ⓡ" /g
@qq@qVdy2G:g/^/m0
Gp
```

Circled letters represent <kbd>Control</kbd> + letter; ␛ is escape.

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Wouldn't this be counted as keystrokes?

Comment: @moo_we_all_do [No.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8999/8478) This is [tag:code-golf] (as opposed to editor golf), so all answers should be scored in bytes.

Comment: The second `@q` causes an infinite loop for me.  It works perfectly if it's removed.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica <s>100</s> 219 bytes

If ASCII-Art need not be Terminal-Art this should be valid.

My earlier submission mistakenly drew a star rather than a hexagon.
I can't see how I was so off!

```
c = CirclePoints@6;
f@s_:=Graphics[{Text[s~StringPart~1,{0,0}],Flatten@Table[Text[StringPart[s,n+1],#]&/@Subdivide[Sequence@@#,n]&/@Partition[Riffle[(n)CirclePoints@6,RotateLeft[n CirclePoints@6]],2],{n,1,StringLength@s-1}]},BaseStyle->20]
```

`CirclePoints@6` returns the vertices of a unit hexagon, assuming that the center is at the origin.

`Subdivide`ing the coordinates for neighboring vertices finds equally spaced positions along the respective edge.

A counter from 1 through the `StringLength -1` of the input string allows each layer of the wordagon to be handled separately.
As `n` increases, so does the respective distance of each vertex from the origin.

`Text[s~StringPart~1,{0,0}]` prints the first letter of the input at the origin.

---

f@"Wordagon"

[image: wordagon]

---

For the curious, this is what the star version looked like.
I know, it was *way* off the mark. It only showed the letters at the hexagon's vertices.

```
Graphics@Table[Text[Style[StringPart[#, r + 1], 54], r {Cos@t, Sin@t}], {t, 0, 2π, π/3}, {r, 0, StringLength@# - 1}] &["Hexa"]
```

[image: hexa]

Comment: Can you post what the star looked like? :D

Comment: Sure.  It's now posted.

Comment: Wow, that is a nice star

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 82 bytes

```
->s{n=s.size-1
(r=-n..n).map{|i|(" "*k=i.abs)+r.map{|j|s[[k+j,k,-j].max]}*" "}*$/}
```

iterates through `1-n..n-1` in both i=y and j=x directions. Without the leading spaces on each line, the output looks like the below, as a result of picking a character from `s`  with the index  `[[i.abs+j,i.abs,-j].max]`. Adding leading spaces forms the required hexagon.

```
f f f f
f l l l f
f l o o l f
f l o G o l f
f l o o l f
f l l l f
f f f f
```

**Ungolfed in test program**

```
f=->s{
  n=s.size-1             n=string length - 1
  (r=-n..n).map{|i|      iterate from -n to n, build an array of lines
    (" "*k=i.abs)+       k=i.abs. Start each line with k spaces.
    r.map{|j|            iterate from -n to n, build an array of characters.
      s[[k+j,k,-j].max]  select character from s (store null string in array if index past end of string)
    }*" "                concatenate the array of characters into a line, separated by spaces
  }*$/                   concatenate the array of lines into a single string, separate by newlines
}

puts f[gets.chomp]
```

**Typical output**

```
   f f f f
  f l l l f
 f l o o l f
f l o G o l f
 f l o o l f
  f l l l f
   f f f f
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 118 bytes

```
s=>[...Array((l=s.length-1)*2+1)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>s[Math.max(i-l,l-i,j-l,i-j,l+l-i-j)]||``).join` `).join`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Based on my answer to [Hexplosive ASCII-art challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92194/hexplosive-ascii-art-challenge) although parts of the solution resemble @LevelRiverSt's Ruby answer. The various components of the `Math.max` produce the following output for `l=3`:

```
    i - l           l - i           j - l            i - j        l + l - i - j
- - - - - - -   3 3 3 3 3 3 3   - - - 0 1 2 3    0 - - - - - -    6 5 4 3 2 1 0
- - - - - - -   2 2 2 2 2 2 2   - - - 0 1 2 3    1 0 - - - - -    5 4 3 2 1 0 -
- - - - - - -   1 1 1 1 1 1 1   - - - 0 1 2 3    2 1 0 - - - -    4 3 2 1 0 - -
0 0 0 0 0 0 0   0 0 0 0 0 0 0   - - - 0 1 2 3    3 2 1 0 - - -    3 2 1 0 - - -
1 1 1 1 1 1 1   - - - - - - -   - - - 0 1 2 3    4 3 2 1 0 - -    2 1 0 - - - -
2 2 2 2 2 2 2   - - - - - - -   - - - 0 1 2 3    5 4 3 2 1 0 -    1 0 - - - - -
3 3 3 3 3 3 3   - - - - - - -   - - - 0 1 2 3    6 5 4 3 2 1 0    0 - - - - - -
```

The maximum value is taken, and the values greater than `l` are removed, thus producing the hexagon shape, while the remaining values map to characters from the string:

```
6 5 4 3 3 3 3      3 3 3 3          a a a a
5 4 3 2 2 2 3     3 2 2 2 3        a x x x a
4 3 2 1 1 2 3    3 2 1 1 2 3      a x e e x a
3 2 1 0 1 2 3   3 2 1 0 1 2 3    a x e h e x a
4 3 2 1 1 2 3    3 2 1 1 2 3      a x e e x a
5 4 3 2 2 2 3     3 2 2 2 3        a x x x a
6 5 4 3 3 3 3      3 3 3 3          a a a a
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 31 bytes

```
R.pvy`¹gN-©×NFs.ø}Sðý®ð×ì})Â¦«»
```

**Explanation**

Utilizing symmetry to only generate the top part of the hexagon, 
then mirroring that to form the lower part.

```
R.pv                     }       # for each prefix of the reversed string
                                 # ['f', 'fl', 'flo', 'floG']
    y`                           # split into chars, ex: 'f', 'l', 'o'
      ¹gN-©×                     # repeat the last char len(input)-N times, 
                                 # where N is the 0-based list index of the current prefix
                                 # ex: 'oo'
            NF   }               # N times do
              s.ø                # surround current char with the next char on stack
                                 # ex: 'floolf'
                  Sðý            # insert spaces between each letter, ex: 'f l o o l f'
                     ®ð×ì        # prefix string with len(input)-N spaces
                                 # ex: '  f l o o l f'
                          )      # wrap all strings in a list
                           Â¦    # create a reversed copy of the list and 
                                 # remove the first item (as we only need the middle once)
                             «»  # concatenate the lists and merge with newlines
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Ui5wdnlgwrlnTi3CqcOXTkZzLsO4fVPDsMO9wq7DsMOXw6x9KcOCwqbCq8K7&input=aGVsbG8)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 104 bytes

```
def f(s):
 for n in range(len(s)*2-1):x=abs(n-len(s)+1);print' '*x+' '.join(s[x+1:][::-1]+s[x]*x+s[x:])
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 202 bytes

```
$w=$argv[1];$l=$i=$a=strlen($w)-1;while(-$l<=$i){$s=join(" ",str_split(str_repeat($w[$l],($a-1)/2).substr($w,$a?$a:1,$l+1),1));echo str_pad("",$a).strrev($s).($a%2?" ":" {$w[$a]} ")."$s
";$a=abs(--$i);}
```

Usage from command line:

```
php.exe -r "put the escaped code here" "put your desired word here"
```

for example:

```
php.exe -r "$w=$argv[1];$l=$i=$a=strlen($w)-1;while(-$l<=$i){$s=join(\" \",str_split(str_repeat($w[$l],($a-1)/2).substr($w,$a?$a:1,$l+1),1));echo str_pad(\"\",$a).strrev($s).($a%2?\" \":\" {$w[$a]} \").\"$s\n\";$a=abs(--$i);}" "example"
```

[Test Suite](http://codepad.org/wXarmGNO).