# HexaGolf: Rotatagons

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, hexagonal-grid

***See also: [Wordagons](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92297/hexagolf-wordagons)***

### Challenge

Given a hexagon and a number `n` as input, output the same hexagon rotated `n` times.

### Hexagon

The hexagon will be a string like so:

```
  a b c
 d d e e
f f o g g
 h h i i
  j k l
```

The hexagon will always be regular and will only ever contain the printable ASCII characters:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

### Rotation

To find how much to rotate the hexagon by, multiply `n` by 60 degrees to get the angle of rotation. For example, using the above hexagon, if `n` is 2, we multiply that by 60 to get 120 degrees. Then, we rotate the hexagon by 120 degrees:

```
  j h f
 k h f d
l i o d a
 i g e b
  g e c
```

Note that each side has moved *two* sides clockwise.

If `n` is positive, you should rotate the hexagon clockwise. If `n` is negative, you should rotate the hexagon anticlockwise.

`n` will always be an integer in the range -6 to 6 inclusive.

### Examples

Input:

```
  . u .
 .  |  .
l - + - r
 .  |  .
  . d .
```

`n` = 3

```
  . d .
 .  |  .
r - + - l
 .  |  .
  . u .
```

---

Input:

```
  - - -
 /     \
<       >
 \     /
  - - -
```

`n` = -1

Output:

```
  - \ >
 -     /
-       -
 /     -
  < \ -
```

---

Input:

```
   h e x a
  g o n s a
 n d t r i a
n g l e s m a
 k e m e s a
  d l y m a
   d d e r
```

`n` = 6

Output:

```
   h e x a
  g o n s a
 n d t r i a
n g l e s m a
 k e m e s a
  d l y m a
   d d e r
```

### Winning

The shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: What do you have against triangles? :P

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Haven't you seen how dangerous their points are? ;)

Comment: Can we take input as a list of lines? Can we assume input is space-padded?

Comment: @Lynn Yep, a list of lines is fine and it will be padded

Comment: Very closely related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51964/15599

Comment: @LevelRiverSt This challenge does support negative integers though

Comment: Well, you can just repeat the code `n%6` times.

Comment: I lost a few minutes trying to be a smartass with CSS' `transform:rotate(x)`. Turns out that wasn't a bright idea, who would have known?

Comment: I know you have space in your possible character list, but do we really need to support characters that are the same as the background character ? Having to use coordinates makes all my solutions a lot longer

Comment: @TonHospel Yes, you need to support hexagons like [this](http://pastebin.com/BKvgXn7i) and [this](http://pastebin.com/JNwrNaRE)

Comment: @BetaDecay Would I be allowed to remove `t.up()` in my program? It leaves extra "pen lines" on the canvas where the turtle moves.

Comment: @mbomb007 Hm, sorry, but since it's an ascii art challenge, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl, <s>120</s> <s>119</s> <s>113</s> <s>107</s> <s>104</s> 102 bytes

Includes +6 for `-0pXi`

Run with the hexagon on STDIN (padded with spaces so all lines have the same length) and the number of rotations after -i.

```
perl -0pXi1 rotagon.pl 
  a b c
 d d e e
f f o g g
 h h i i
  j k l
^D
```

`rotagon.pl`

```
s!(.)!$X=(3*($w=y/
//*2)/4+($-="@-"/$w)-"@+"%$w)/2*--$w+2*$--.25;/^\C{$X}(.)/;$1!eg while$^I--%6
```

Finally got the rotation matrix to be shorter than the old double loop

Comment: I had to add the `a` and `n` flags to get this to work.

Comment: @Neil That is only needed on old perl versions. In recent perls `-F` implies `-a` and `-a` in turn implies `-n`

Answer (score 14):

## Python 2, <s>160</s> <s>158</s> <s>156</s> <s>148</s> 124 bytes

***Prepare to be amazed!*** The resulting text is drawn on a canvas... by a [`Turtle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html)! :D

```python
from turtle import*
h,n=input()
up()
rt(n*60)
l=0
for c in h:
 write(c);fd(9);l-=1
 if" ">c:fd(9*l);rt(90);fd(15);lt(90);l=0
```

[**Try it online**](https://trinket.io/python/132af14245) - Supports decimal rotations as well!

---

If you would prefer the turtle to be shaped like one, you can add the line `t.shape("turtle")`.

View the revision history to see past versions.

**Aliases used**:

`up()` - `penup()`

`rt()` - `right()`

`lt()` - `left()`

`fd()` - `forward()`

`bk()` - `backward()`

*Thanks to [Sherlock9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47581/sherlock9) for the [suggestions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32192714#32192714)!*

Comment: 7 more until you beat standard python!

Comment: @EasterlyIrk If only `t.write('\n')` worked...

Comment: @EasterlyIrk If I could remove `t.up()`, I'd be there.

Comment: Congrats! You are beating normal python!

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2.7, 151 bytes

```python
h,n=input()
s=1-len(h)
e=enumerate
exec n%6*"h=[''.join(c>' 'and h[y-x-3*s/2>>1][x*2+y*6+s>>2]or c for x,c in e(l))for y,l in e(h)];"
print'\n'.join(h)
```

Example:

```
% python2.7 hexarot.py <<<'[["   h e x a   ","  g o n s a  "," n d t r i a ","n g l e s m a", " k e m e s a ","  d l y m a  ","   d d e r   "],-1]'
   a a a a   
  x s i m a  
 e n r s s a 
h o t e e m r
 g d l m y e 
  n g e l d  
   n k d d
```

Comment: @mbomb007 That won't work because of the order of operations, the subtractions will happen before the bitshift.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>130</s> 127 bytes

```
f=(s,n)=>n%6?f(s.split`
`.map((s,i,a)=>s.replace(/./g,(c,j)=>(a[(i+z-j)/2+z]||c)[(i+j-z)/2+i]||c,z=a.length>>1)).join`
`,n-1):s
```

Originally based on my answer to [Rotate a diamond tiling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52220/rotate-a-diamond-tiling) although I might now be able to rewrite that answer along the lines of this answer.